# WordPress Importer 0.5

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't install WordPress Importer 0.5 on Boldy theme.

the message i get when installing the plugin is this:

```
Warning: touch() [function.touch]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 10736 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /var/www/vhosts/griffedecorazioni.it/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 177

Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 10736 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /var/www/vhosts/griffedecorazioni.it/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 489

Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
............
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the constant `WP_TEMP_DIR` which should change the directory downloaded packages are saved to. Put something like this in your `wp_config.php`:

> define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/');